# Exported camera has incorrect scale and rotation

Tags: animation, camera, scale, .fbx

I have an FBX file with camera trajectory:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bzuNDUEPAbt1DBfECdoQ226avFtGBQu0/view?usp=sharing
This file is created in 3ds max. If I load it in my program, I see correct initial position, scale and rotation:

```
Position: 7.62939e-06, 30, -51.962
Rotation quaternion: scalar:0.683013, vector:(0.183013, -0.683013, -0.183013)
Rotation euler: 0, -90, -30
Scale:  QVector3D(1, 1, 1)
```

If I import this FBX file in Blender 2.91 and then export again to FBX all the values get broken:

```
Position: 1.93787e-05, 76.2, -131.983
Rotation quaternion: scalar:0.894386, vector:(0.354992, 1.32485, 0.354992)
Rotation euler: -6.19351, 109.213, 34.4245
Scale: 2.54, 2.54, 2.54
```

I tried different exporting settings, but nothing affects the situation. Is it possible to export the camera to FBX from Blender and get the correct scale, position and rotation?